# How to be approved or reviewed on cardano-token-registry?

Tags: metadata, token

I made a pull request on cardano-token-registry
but after days it's still blocked.

How to ask for a review or some type of approval?

My request is #1030

Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wait, because these are reviewed by human beings working at the Cardano Foundation and it might take few days to work the back queue.

Comment: I must say that it's quite frustrating being leaved in a limbo for days just because the first CI run failed for an error in another project and not in mine. However, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Merged! Frustration ended! :P